# Android AppCompat ToolBar color can't be changed to white

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar, android-appcompat

I attempted the following:

```
<style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
</style>
```

To change my toolbar text color to white, but it's still black!

What do I need to change?

Comment: I've set up my toolbar in a similar way to this https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ae63392e1c70bc33af8b and you change its colour in the xml. Its worked really well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using Toolbar? If yes, then your myAppTheme should extend from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar ... Toolbar is a replacement of ActionBar. Therefore if you want to use it then you must remove ActionBar styles from your xml.

I suggest you read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) blog post. And [here](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) is a nice implementation on how to change title color.

Comment: Thanks! Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar didn't work whereas your suggestion fixed it!

Comment: Toolbar can work also with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar or Theme.AppCompat.Light.